# Button Touch Only Works Once

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, target, ibaction

For some reason, interaction with my UIButton only works once.  I've tried both via IBAction, and by IBOutlet with "addTarget".  I have no idea why.

Context:

BaseViewController

```
- (IBAction) button_touched:(id)sender; //<-- Declared here, but not implemented
- (void)userInputReceived:(BOOL)bSuccess; //<-- Declared here, but not implemented
```

ViewController1 : BaseViewController

```
- (IBAction) button_touched:(id)sender; //<-- Implemented here
- (void)userInputReceived:(BOOL)bSuccess; //<-- Implemented here
```

Also, this is where I try "addTarget" but that doesn't work either (first touch works, but not the second)

In the "button_touched" method of ViewController1 (vc1), I make a call to another class like this:

```
[someOtherClassObject doSomethingWithMyView:self];
```

That class simply pops up a message box, gets user input, then calls back on the viewcontroller:

(Inside SomeOtherClass):

```
-(void)doSomethingWithMyView:(BaseViewController*)vc
{
    // Do Something
    [vc userInputReceived:TRUE];
}
```

Once this workflow has executed once, the button touch never calls the "button_touch" method again.  No matter what I do, I can't get this to be called again.

In a thread on one of the popular BBS forums, someone mentioned that a problem like this could be caused by not having the object (vc1) you think you do, but rather, another instance of it.  So, I logged the instance like NSLog( "instance: %p", self) in numerous places, and it's always the same.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.  This is very frustrating.

Comment: Can you post all of your code from your button_touched: method? As well, how exactly did you connect your button to the IBAction, and what kind of touch is is looking for?

Answer (score 0):

shot in the dark maybe, but its possible that your view controller's view has lost first responder status due to the displaying of the message inside the other object (what type of object is this and how is the message displayed?).

Try after your statement:

```
[vc userInputReceived:TRUE];
```

adding the line

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow makeFirstResponder:vc.view];
```

Comment: Good thought, but no dice.  I finally figured out what it was, and no way anyone could have found it without seeing a lot of my code.  However, just in case anyone else has a similar problem, be sure to check your code paths carefully.  I was clearing an object in my base class that needed to be cleared for one subclass, but not for the other.  This clearing of data is what was causing the subsequent messages to not be fired--I checked for nil before sending the message.  Terrible, I know, and I hope I didn't waste a lot of time, but hopefully this will save someone else time, too. :)